Why are open half-disks diffeomorphic to upper half plane. Needed for proof of Stokes theorem in Intro. to smooth manifolds" by Tu
I am reading Tu's book "Introduction to manifolds". In the proof of Stokes Theorem it says:

I can't find this statement in exercise 1.5. Furthermore I am not sure how to prove it.
Why to we need it? Can't $\phi(U)$ be used? Why do we need the whole half-space?
Many thanks in advance.

These are several different questions.To answer the question in the title: Here is a diffeomorphism $\Phi$  from the half ball (half disk if $n=2$) $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; x_1 > 0, \, \|x\|< 1\}$  to the upper half space (half plane if $n = 2$)  $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; x_1 > 0\}$, with inverse $\Phi^{-1}$.
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{1 - \|x\|}x, \quad \Phi^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{1+\|y\|}y
$$

Okay, that was easier than I expected. Basically the same as for open ball and R^n? Regarding the other questions, it would be possible to to use $\phi(U)$, wouldn't it?

Please provide more context. This should now be a new question. .
